# How to send mail from linux system with linux_username in 'from' field and account@gmail.com in 'to' field

Tags: mail

I'm using mailutils and sendmail, I have installed it and configured using command 'sudo sendmailconfig'. When I use command

echo "Message Body" | mail -s "Message Subject" receiver@gmail.com

nothing happens, I don't receive any email.

I want that mail should come from my system(not from other gmail account) to my gmail account(receiver@gmail.com)

I have tried postfix too but nothing happens. I am able to send mail from one gmail account to another gmail account using ssmtp.

Comment: The main problem might be, that your mail is rejected by googlemails spam filters. Check for returning mail in your user's inbox. Dynamic IPs are usually on blacklist mail providers use for spam prevention.

Comment: a) Buy a domain including mail address service, use that address and forward mail via it. b) Project sounds like university? Use the universities smarthost system and send it from there. c) Proper SPF and DKIM setups. ... no trivial task, spam ruined simple mail servers as simple mail servers made spam too easy

Comment: Can I use linux server for sending mails ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You PC IS a mail server when you send mail via the `mail` command. To use a smarthost you'll have to adapt the postfix (or exim) settings.

Comment: I am very new to all this. So how do I adopt to postfix settings.

Comment: Please search for one of the plenty guides out there. First of all you need to know which smarthost even is available to you (if any).